# For which measure spaces X is the k-fold tensor-product of L^2(X) isomorphic to L^2(X^k)?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

For example, if $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual Lebesuge measure, then there is a natural map $$\Phi:L^2(X)\otimes L^2(X)\ni f\otimes g\mapsto((x,y)\mapsto f(x)g(y))\in L^2(X^2)$$ which is also unitary map between Hilbert spaces, by Fubinis theorem (which requires $X$ and $Y$ to be complete and $\sigma$-finite).

Comment: I am not an expert but I imagine that you will have to take some sort of completed tensor product, and that once you do that this will be true for all $X$. (The reason for the completion is that your map will only hit functions that are finite sums of functions on $X$ times functions on $Y$, but you can write functions which aren't of this form.)

Comment: Thats true and I have implicitly assumed that when saying that $\Phi$ is a unitary map between *Hilbert* spaces, so $L^2(X)\otimes L^2(X)$ is to be taken as the tensor product between Hilbert spaces, which is exactly what you said: the completion of the algebraic tensor product with respect to the canonical inner product. But nevertheless I could have pointed this out more clearly, thanks!

Comment: oh I see, sorry!